# How to add list in tabs

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-fragments, tabs

How to make a program like this:
MainActivity have a button that make the program open TabsActivity.
TabsActivity have 3 tabs, each tab (fragment) have a list.

I tried to do this following some tutorials, but I had no success. I had problems to pass the fragment (tab) to a function of a BaseAdapter class that required an Context object.

BaseAdapter class:

```
public class AdapterListView extends BaseAdapter
{ ... }
```

Function (constructor) of the BaseAdapter class :

```
public AdapterListView(Context context, ArrayList<ItemListView> itens)
{ ... }
```

Fragment class:

```
public class FristTabFragment extends Fragment implements OnItemClickListener
{ ... }
```

Using function in the fragment:

```
private AdapterListView adapterListView;
adapterListView = new AdapterListView(this, itens);
```

The compiler (eclipse) says that the constructor AdapterListView that accept FirstTabFragment as a argument is undefined. The AdapterListView constructor needs a Context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass an activity that contains the Fragment to the constructor. Use Fragment's `getActivity()` metod instead of `this`.

Comment: This solved. Thanks!!! I just have another problem now: the program crashes before display the tabs.